# Which Universal Windows Apps do support LaunchUriForResultsAsync?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In Universal Windows Platform it is possible for one app to communicate with an another one and to exchange data between the both. This kind of two-way app-to-app communications between Universal Windows Applications is called "Launch an app for results", carried out using the method `LaunchUriForResultsAsync` and is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results).

Now, I need real-world apps that can be addressed using this approach to take advantage of the functionalities they provide. All the examples I could find are just about using the `LaunchUriAsync` method, i.e. about the one-way communication, where the caller app can pass some data to the called one, but no data is passed back from the called app to the caller.

How can I find such UWP apps that support `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`?

Comment: Hello, what problems did you encounter while reading the documentation?  You can write out the problems you encountered when writing the code.

Comment: Hello, no problems with the documentation nor with writing the code. Both are clear. But I need examples of existing real-world applications that can be launched for results.

Comment: I‘m sorry, but Microsoft does not provide such a code example. Every developer's needs are different. If you need an actual project that includes `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`, you can search for related code in Github.

Comment: There is no central catalog of apps that support LaunchUriForResultsAsync.